# StandardScaler error due to too large values (Python). Preprocessing time series data

Tags: python, scaletransform

I need to center and scale my data, my predictor matrix X has a column with too large numbers. How can I deal with this variable to apply standardization? When I use `preprocessing.StandardScaler()` function in python I got this message:

> "ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float64')."

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Check that your matrix does not contain `NaN` or `np.inf` values.

Comment: Yes, my matrix contains inf values. How can we deal with this kind of data? Do we need to use a prior transformation?

Comment: You need to figure out how to remove/replace them in your data. Thinking about it logically, what is the mean of infinity? What is the standard deviation of infinity?  How would any scaling process work with infinite values, or any model for that matter? An infinite value would mean an infinite squared error,